# How To Compare Data With Inline Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I've been having a lot of trouble figuring this out. So I'm using inline Assembly and I'm basically trying to compare a number the user types in using Scanf with the number "$20."

But I think it's comparing the location rather than the actual value.

Here is what I have:

```
asm(
    "main:                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    "push $msg                                                                                             \n"
    "call _printf                                                                                              \n"
    "add $4, %esp                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    "push $gus                                                                                              \n"
    "push $fmt                                                                                              \n"
    "call _scanf                                                                                              \n"
    "add $8, %esp                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    "movl $20, %eax                                                                                         \n"
    "movl $gus, %ebx                                                                                          \n"
    "cmp %eax, %ebx                                                                                             \n"
    "jg lower                                                                                              \n"
    "jl higher                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    "lower:                                                                                              \n"
    "push $lss                                                                                              \n"
    "call _printf                                                                                              \n"
    "add $4, %esp                                                                                              \n"
    "jmp next                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    "higher:                                                                                              \n"
    "push $gtr                                                                                              \n"
    "call _printf                                                                                              \n"
    "add $4, %esp                                                                                              \n"
    "jmp next                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    "next:                                                                                              \n"
    "jmp main                                                                                              \n"
    "ret                                                                                              \n"
    "                                                                                              \n"
    ".section .data                                                                                              \n"
    "msg: .asciz \"Please enter your guess: \"                                                                                              \n"
    "gtr: .asciz \"Higher! \"                                                                                     \n"
    "lss: .asciz \"Lower! \"                                                                               \n"
 //   "crr: .asciz \"Please enter your guess: \"                                                                                              \n"
    "fmt: .asciz \"%d\"                                                                                              \n"
    ".double 100                                                                                             \n"
    ".byte 0                                                                                             \n"
    "gus: .double 100                                                                                             \n"
    ".byte 0                                                                                         \n"
    );
```

Yes, I know there really isn't a point in this code for actual use. The purpose of me writing this is really just to figure out how comparisons.

But my problem is, at:

```
 "movl $20, %eax                                                                                         \n"
"movl $gus, %ebx                                                                                          \n"
"cmp %eax, %ebx
```

It's supposed to compare 20 with the "gus", or the "guess" the user typed in. But it always says "Lower" no matter what they type in.

Comment: If `push $gus` pushes the address of the variable that will hold the user input, won't `movl $gus, %ebx` put the address of rather than the value of `gus` into `ebx`? I'm unfamiliar with AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load the address of `gus`, not its value, to EBX before comparing.

Your bigger problem is that you try to do way too much with inline assembly.
You want to compare in assembly? Very well, compare. But why call `printf` and `scanf` and all the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I admit that the flavor of assembly I've used is slightly different, but does $20 not use the value in register 20, not the literal value 20? Depending on how this assembly works, you should either compare to 20 as an immediate value, or you should load 20 into a register and compare to that register.

Comment: No, there is no register 20, and $ denotes immediate.